# How do I detect if a certain other application is clicked to open? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

Is there a way that I can get vb.net to detect if the window/form of an external .exe is clicked?

I have looked into the deactivate event but can't get it to work, and I am unsure if this is what I need to achieve my desired result:

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.Deactivate
    MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Deactivate event.")
End Sub
```

The error I get when running the above code is as follows:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

This says nothing recognizable to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Normally there is no way, unless you can hack the Windows message queue and peek on all mouse events... which is possible but good luck with that... Check on MSDN what this event does...

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to detect the click, but there is a workaround.  You can set a timer to run (every half second in this example) to check to see if the application is running:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 500  'in milliseconds
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim yourProcess() As Process

    yourProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")

    If yourProcess.Count > 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False   'Stop the timer
        MessageBox.Show("Your application has been opened!")
    End If
End Sub
```

This example checks to see if Notepad is open.  If it is not already open, it will continue to check until it is opened, which is pretty much what you are asking for (except there is no click involved).  To add the timer, go to your form designer view and simply drag or double click the "timer" control to put on your form, and this code will be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... Instead of form1.Deactivate it should be Me.Deactivate